# Error: Compile Error: Entity is not api accessible at line 1 column 1

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create trigger for some events. But it is giving me compilation error: `Error: Compile Error: Entity is not api accessible at line 1 column 1`

Here is my code:

```
trigger SendEmailonProjectCompletion on Project__c (After Insert, After Update) {
     for(Project p : Trigger.New){
     }

}
```

This error happens after adding following code:

```
 for(Project p : Trigger.New){
         }
```

Without this code, there is no compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference the custom object

```
 for(Project__c p : Trigger.New){
     }
```

An object without `__c` is considered a standard object by SFDC and some of these, like `Project` could easily be real SObjects just not licensed to your edition or enabled by Setup.

Comment: np -- you had an easy one, sometimes the same error occurs somewhere in 500 lines of code and it is more difficult to figure out why as the line# is often `1`